# AngularJS: Directive not working for elements inserted via AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a page which has a modal window(AngularUI bootstrap modal directive). DOM for this modal box is being loaded dynamically from server. This modal box is opened when a button on page is clicked.

Inside this modal box there is another directive applied on a anchor element. This directive is for selecting and uploading files.

The issue is that the file upload directive is working(i.e. opening the file select dialog of windows) if I keep it anywhere on parent page but does not work if I keep it inside the modal box.

My understanding why the directive is not working is that DOM for modal is being loaded later and Angular finishes attaching events by the time user opens the modal box.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load content of your modal via [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude).